# Will SQL Server backup contain master key, symmetric key and certificate?

Tags: sql-server, encryption, database-backups

I am going to change my SQL server database from one SQL server to another SQL server. And I am using encrypted columns(varbinary) in my database.

My question is after restoring my database backup in new SQL Server, Will it affect while decrypting the encrypted columns due to master key, symmetric key and certificate?

I hope If these keys and certificates are also restored with data, It will be fine.

Comment: Possibly a bitter fit for [Stack DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: SQL Server backups contain everything that's stored *within the database* - things that are stored at the server level are **not** part of a database backup